# MYSQL query to get number of employees Working in Current year and Past Years

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have been stuck on this query where i have to select the employees who are working in company for past 5 years.

```
e-g 
in 2010 1 employee Registered  so  Total Employees in 2010 1
in 2011 2 employees Registered so Total Emloyees in 2013 3
in 2012 4 employees Registered and 1 left so Total Employees in 2012 6
in 2013 5 employees Registered and 2 left So Total Employees in 2013 9
in 2014 No New employee Registered or Left So Same as Same
etc
```

So in end employees Report is like

```
(2010), (2011), (2012), (2013), (2014)
   1      3       6        9       9
```

now i am stucked how can i achieve this in mysql query.

I have table **Employee** where employee info is registered.
[image]

Have **Employement** Table where if employee is registered then join date is assigned and if left then end date is assigned.
[image]

Also There is then **gender** table to show in year how many males and how many females are working in company.
[image]

Finally here is the Query i tried.. but this is not the right query. i am missing something here in the query but i cant quite get that.

```
SELECT MLGT.`gender_type_title`,MLGT.`gender_type_id` AS GenderID,COUNT(E.`gender`) AS TotalGenders,ET.`joining_date`
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN employment ET
ON E.`employee_id` = ET.`employee_id` AND ET.`current` = 1 AND ET.`trashed`=0
INNER JOIN ml_gender_type MLGT
ON E.`gender` = MLGT.`gender_type_id` AND MLGT.`trashed`=0
WHERE E.`trashed`=0 AND ET.`joining_date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 YEAR) AND ET.`current`= 1
GROUP BY E.`gender`, YEAR(ET.`joining_date`);
```

[image]

Comment: So you want year wise sum of male and female employees who havnt left

Answer (score 0):

You need another table (or constant sub query) to have the year list you want to group by. Make a join between this new table and the employment one with a condition on joining date comparison. Then count the results :)

Comment: can you please give example, sorry i'm not that good in queries.

Comment: I have no more mysql installed to create a example, so I can't give you accurate example, but this is basic stuff (join, where, count, group by, having)
Look at the result at each step I told you, and you'll see the next step to apply to have the desired numbers.
In general, never try to write a full query of various lines in one block, but make small iteration to reach your goal, this is the way to make complex queries work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This query

```
    SELECT YEAR(ET.`joining_date`) as Year, MLGT.`gender_type_title` as Gender, count(E.employee_id) as Emp_count
    FROM employee E
    INNER JOIN employment ET
    ON E.`employee_id` = ET.`employee_id` AND ET.`current` = 1 AND ET.`trashed`=0
    INNER JOIN ml_gender_type MLGT
    WHERE E.`trashed`=0 AND ET.`joining_date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 YEAR) AND ET.`current`= 1
    GROUP BY Year, Gender;
```

Comment: Thankyou for response, but your query is only showing for male genders?